# Onclick function on checkbox still functioning even if it's replaced with other function by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm planning to let the user when clicked on one of the radio button A, and B:

A - will allow the user to check the checbox with the javascript replaced the onclick function checkRequired(), where the function will remove the "required" from the input once its checked.

B - will only allow the user check only 1 checkbox with the function of checkOne(), replaced the function checkRequired()

The problem is I don't understand why the javascript keeps on using the checkOne() function, even if I've checked the entire code and syntax, even the developer tool from Google Chrome browser DID SHOW THE FUNCTION HAS BEEN REPLACED BY checkRequired() ONCE THE RADIO BUTTON A IS CHECKED. Logically speaking IT SHOULD WORKING WELL, BUT for some reason it's not working at all.

```
function checkRequired() {
        var n = $( "input:checkbox:checked" ).length;
        var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
        var chkboxes = $(':checkbox');
        if(n < 1) {
            chkboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        } else {
            requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
        }
    }


function checkOne() {
        $('.regid-chkbox').on('change', function() {
           $('.regid-chkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }


function editMeal() {
        var editBrand = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-brand");
        var editInfo = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-info");

        if (editBrand.checked){
            $('.regid-chkbox').removeAttr('onclick');
            $('.regid-chkbox').attr('onclick', 'checkRequired();');
        } else if (editInfo.checked) {
            /* Making the checkbox only one can be checked */
            $('.regid-chkbox').removeAttr('onclick');
            $('.regid-chkbox').attr('onclick', 'checkOne();');
        }
    }
```

HTML Codes:

```
<div class="logmod__tab lgm-2" id="ver-form-res">
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <div class="logmod__heading">
          <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your information to verify and <strong>edit the meal.</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__form">
        <!-- Upload Image Section -->
         <center>
           <div id="wrapper" class="img-container">
            <img id="output_image" src="image/e2.png" class="preview-img"/>
            <div class="upload-text-container">
              <div class="upload-text"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i><br> Click here to Upload </div>
            </div>
            <input type="file" onchange="preview_image(event)" style="display: none;" name="bran-img" id="bran-image-reg">
           </div>
         </center>
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input full" style="height:auto!important;">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-account-code-dis">Edit Categories*</label>
                <label class="radio-container"> EDIT MEAL\'S BRAND
                  <input required type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="radio-edit-meal-brand" name="meal-edit" onclick="editMeal()">
                  <span class="checkmark-radio"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="radio-container"> EDIT MEAL\'S INFO
                  <input required type="radio" value="1" id="radio-edit-meal-info" name="meal-edit" onclick="editMeal()">
                  <span class="checkmark-radio"></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input full">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-account-code-res">Account Code*</label>
                <input class="string optional" name="enable-acccode" maxlength="8" minlength="8" id="user-account-code-res" placeholder="Account Code" type="password" size="8" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input string optional">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-res">Password *</label>
                <input class="string optional first-pw" name="enable-pw" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-res" onkeyup="check_verlist_res();" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50" />
              </div>
              <div class="input string optional">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat-res">Repeat password *</label>
                <input class="string optional" name="enable-pw-repeat" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat-res" onkeyup="check_verlist_res();" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password" size="50" />
                <span class="hide-password" id="toggle-pw-res" onclick="togglePassResA();">SHOW</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs" id="edit-brand-meal">
              <div class="input full" style="height:80px!important">
                <label class="string optional" for="vercode-role">BRAND *</label>
                <select class="role-select" id="brand-type-meal" name="meal-edit-brand" style="width:30vw; height:4vh;">
                  <option value="" selected disabled>BRAND</option>
                  <!-- call out the brand value -->
                  ';
                    $BRANDTYPE = "SELECT * FROM meal_brand WHERE active = 1";
                    $result = $con->query($BRANDTYPE);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '
                        <option value="'.$row["brand_id"].'">' .$row["brand_name"]. '</option>
                        ';
                      }
                    }
                echo
                '</select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs" id="edit-info-meal-1">
              <div class="input input string optional">
                <label class="string optional" for="meal-name-edit">Meal Name *</label>
                <input class="string optional meal-name" name="meal-name-edit" maxlength="255" id="meal-name-edit" placeholder="Meal Name"/>
              </div>
              <div class="input input string optional">
                <label class="string optional" for="meal-quantity-edit">Meal Default Quantity *</label>
                <input class="string optional meal-quantity" type="number" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="validate(event)" name="meal-quantity-edit" id="meal-quantity-edit" placeholder="00"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs" id="edit-info-meal-2">
              <div class="input input string optional" style="height:80px!important">
                <label class="string optional" for="meal-edit-info-brand">BRAND *</label>
                <select class="role-select" id="brand-type-meal-info" name="meal-edit-info-brand" style="width:30vw; height:4vh;">
                  <option value="" selected disabled>BRAND</option>
                  <!-- call out the brand value -->
                  ';
                    $BRANDTYPE = "SELECT * FROM meal_brand WHERE active = 1";
                    $result = $con->query($BRANDTYPE);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '
                        <option value="'.$row["brand_id"].'">' .$row["brand_name"]. '</option>
                        ';
                      }
                    }
                echo
                '</select>
              </div>
              <div class="input input string optional" style="height:80px!important">
                <label class="string optional" for="meal-price-edit">Meal Price *</label>
                <input class="string optional meal-price" type="number" step="0.25" min="1" onkeypress="validate(event)" name="meal-price-edit" id="meal-price-edit" placeholder="RM 0.00"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs" id="edit-info-meal-3">
              <div class="input full" style="height:30vh!important;">
                <label class="string optional" for="meal-details-edit">Meal Details*</label>
                <textarea style="height:20vh!important;width:68vw!important" class="string optional meal-details" type="textarea" name="meal-details-edit" id="meal-details-edit" placeholder="Meal Details" /></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="simform__actions">
              <input disabled class="sumbit" name="submit-list-edit-meal" style="font-family:oswald!important;" type="submit" id="submit-res" value="Confirm Edit" />
              <div id="error-message-res" style="font-size:17px;"></div>
              <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By editing the brand, you are here and agree our <a class="special" onclick="return false;" role="link">Terms & Conditions</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

The expected result should be working under these condition, but for some reason it's not working even if the developer tool from Chrome shown the function already been replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

I have found the problem. In `checkOne` you set the `onChange` event and we never unset it. That's why the check stays even when you switch radio buttons.

Try:

```
function editMeal() {
    var editBrand = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-brand");
    var editInfo = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-info");

    if (editBrand.checked){
        $('.regid-chkbox').off('click');
        $('.regid-chkbox').off('change');
        $('.regid-chkbox').on('click', checkRequired);
    } else if (editInfo.checked) {
        /* Making the checkbox only one can be checked */
        $('.regid-chkbox').off('click');
        $('.regid-chkbox').off('change');
        $('.regid-chkbox').on('click', checkOne);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I made a quick mock-up code snippet and that seems to work the way you desired. Is there any other place you are modifying event handlers that can cause your issue?

```js
function checkRequired() {
    console.log('Check required');
}

function checkOne() {
    console.log('check one');
}

function editMeal() {
      var editBrand = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-brand");
      var editInfo = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-info");
      if (editBrand.checked){
          $('.regid-checkbox').off('click');
          $('.regid-checkbox').on('click', checkRequired);
      } else if (editInfo.checked) {
          /* Making the checkbox only one can be checked */
          $('.regid-checkbox').off('click');
          $('.regid-checkbox').on('click', checkOne);
      }
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', editMeal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-edit-meal-brand" name="edit-meal"><label for="radio-edit-meal-brand">Check Required</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-edit-meal-info" name="edit-meal"><label for="radio-edit-meal-info">Check One</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="regid-checkbox">
</form>
```

---

**Original:**

Maybe using event handler syntax instead of setting the attr `onclick`?

```
function editMeal() {
    var editBrand = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-brand");
    var editInfo = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-info");

    if (editBrand.checked){
        $('.regid-chkbox').off('click');
        $('.regid-chkbox').on('click', checkRequired);
    } else if (editInfo.checked) {
        /* Making the checkbox only one can be checked */
        $('.regid-chkbox').off('click');
        $('.regid-chkbox').on('click', checkOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, it still using the checkOne() function.

Comment: Okay, I realized that this odd scenario will occurred once the function has been replaced to checkOne() and if you checked the checkbox at least once, otherwise if the function replaced with checkOne() and you didnt check any checkbox yet, the javascript seems wont use the checkOne() function, but the checkRequired() when it's replaced with checkRequired() function.

Comment: @MEMYSELF I think I found the issue, please let me know if updated (Edit 2) change fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you correct the attribute to be `.attr('onClick')` instead of `.attr('onclick')`. This is case sensitive.

Although, as kht pointed out it may make more sense to just use the `on('click')` function instead.

Comment: Tried, it still using the checkOne() function. >_<

Comment: Will you add the HTML?

Comment: Preferably the related

Comment: It contains some PHP code, I hope you wouldn't mind that.

Edited in the post.

Comment: Can you put the HTML after it's been processed by PHP?

Comment: It's kinda long tho because the PHP calls out quite some of the records from the database. Edited in the post.

Comment: Nevermind, its too dam long, heres the link to the related codes.

https://codeshare.io/5wxLBR

Comment: Just search for the keyword "radio-edit-meal-brand" then you will saw the related codes with the question

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer kht posted, even the original unmodified Javascript OP posted works as expected.

```js
function checkRequired() {
  console.log('checkRequired');
  var n = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
  var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
  var chkboxes = $(':checkbox');
  if (n < 1) {
    chkboxes.attr('required', 'required');
  } else {
    requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
  }
}


function checkOne() {
  console.log('checkOne');
  $('.regid-chkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('.regid-chkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
}


function editMeal() {
  var editBrand = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-brand");
  var editInfo = document.getElementById("radio-edit-meal-info");

  if (editBrand.checked) {
    $('.regid-chkbox').removeAttr('onclick');
    $('.regid-chkbox').attr('onclick', 'checkRequired();');
  } else if (editInfo.checked) {
    /* Making the checkbox only one can be checked */
    $('.regid-chkbox').removeAttr('onclick');
    $('.regid-chkbox').attr('onclick', 'checkOne();');
  }
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', editMeal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-edit-meal-brand" name="edit-meal"><label for="radio-edit-meal-brand">Check Required</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-edit-meal-info" name="edit-meal"><label for="radio-edit-meal-info">Check One</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="regid-chkbox" />
</form>
```